# Hacer focus en un boton dependiendo del valor de un atributo javascript - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Al boton le creo un atributo que se llama (idproducto) a ese atributo le poncho el id de cada producto que tengo, asi se diferencia cada boton para despues que cuando le den click se agregre a la lista de compras, al momento de filtrar los productos, hago que se oculten los productos que no tienen que ver nada con el texto de busqueda, estoy haciendo que al darle la tecla de flecha hacia abajo, pues me pase al otro boton de agregar del siguiente producto, pero como hay un  que se oculta entre el producto en el que estoy parado y el que quiero que me haga focus no lo hace, se me pierde. Entonces estoy intentando hacer focus en el siguiente boton que no este oculto, pero no hace focus, e intentado con varias cosas, con tab si pasa perfectamente, pero lo quiero hacer con la tecla de flechas

```
var idProducto = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children().next("tr:visible").children().children().children("button").attr("idproducto");
```

aquí agarro el valor del atributo, Y quiero hacerle focus al boton que tiene ese valor (idProducto)

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children().next("tr:visible").children().children().children("button").focus();
```

se traen varios registros, y me toca hacerlo de esta forma, Gracias

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, te recomiendo usar closest() en vez de todos esos parent() que tienes, también te recomiendo que crees un ejemplo funcional y lo agregues al snippet, puedes leer [ask] para organizar mejor tu pregunta

Comment: A qué te refieres con 'valor'? Entiendo que obtienes el texto de una propiedad, entonces necesitas que el botón tenga como texto la propiedad que obtuviste anteriormente?

Comment: @FernandoChamorro Amplie la descripcion

Comment: @BenderPaisa Amplie la descripcion